# Custom role based users are not able to access wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles, capabilities

First of all I am a WordPress learner. So sorry if my code looks stupid!

I have created a custom theme with a custom user role. I am not developing any plugin.

In my fucntions.php file I have written the following code to create a User role. Users assigned to this role are supposed to login to the admin but only be able to access their Profile pages.

```
add_action('init', 'yrc_cst_register_role_customer_service_rep');

/**
 * Register new user role
 */

function yrc_cst_register_role_customer_service_rep() {

    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $wp_roles->remove_role('subscriber');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('editor');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('contributor');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('author');

    $service_rep_caps = array(
        'read'              => false,
        'create_posts'      => false,
        'edit_posts'        => false,
        'edit_others_posts' => false,
        'publish_posts'     => false,
        'manage_categories' => false,
        'manage_options'    => false,
    );

    add_role('customer_service', __('Customer Service'), $service_rep_caps);
}
```

I have removed all roles except Administrator, because no other role is required for this portal. Administrator will only create Users with **Customer Service** role.

I have no third party plugin installed in the system.

Users with the custom role are able to login to the system through a custom login page which is working OK. But whenever they are trying to access their Profile page the following error message comes up:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

Is there anything like `'edit_profile' => true`?

I must be doing something wrong but my limited knowledge is not enough to figure this out. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `read` capability must be set to `true`, so they can access.

Keep in mind, roles are saved to the database, when you run it on every `init` action, this is considered to be time consuming.

The Codex suggests to run those actions in the `register_activation_hook()`. Since you are using this code in your theme, you might want to check, if the role exists.

Since you are running this in a theme, this might be a workaround:

```
function yrc_cst_register_role_customer_service_rep() {

    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    //$wp_roles->remove_role('customer_service'); // Remove it only for test purposes.

    if ( $wp_roles->is_role( 'customer_service' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $wp_roles->remove_role('subscriber');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('editor');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('contributor');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('author');


    $service_rep_caps = array(
        'read'  => true,
    );
    add_role('customer_service', __('Customer Service'), $service_rep_caps);

}
```

Comment: I changed to `'read' => true,` but still cannot gain access to admin. :(

Comment: Did you try it with a newly created user, after you switched the rights?

Comment: Yes, I just did and still no luck. Getting the same error.

Comment: @SubrataSarkar Try `remove_role('customer_service');` and add again